# Is OWIN only for ASP.net Identity? Can't we use owin context to query our application db?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, owin, identity

I am very new to EF, ASP.Net MVC, ASP.net Identity etc.

I am creating a simple e-commerce website for learning above mentioned stuff. My query is, how can I query the application database?

Is OWIN context only used for ASP.net Identity?

Comment: if by query the application database you mean get data from your sql server of choice, then no.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that context should only be used for asp.net identity

OWIN and asp.net identity are completely separate concepts :

**ASP.Net Identity :** This framework is used for user management/authentication mechanism etc. For more detail please [Follow this link](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity)

**OWIN  :** Owin defines an abstraction between .NET web servers and web applications. By decoupling the web server from the application, OWIN makes it easier to create middleware for .NET web development. Also, OWIN makes it easier to port web applications to other hosts—for example, self-hosting in a Windows service or other process. For more information follow [this link](http://www.asp.net/aspnet/overview/owin-and-katana/getting-started-with-owin-and-katana)

Now what you are trying to do is that you want to use entity framework to query the database in various scenarios. So for that you should create a custom context, define your schema in it and do whatever query you want to do over that.

To know more about **entity framework** you can start from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-in/data/ee712907)